# What permissions are needed for the Azure DevOps Deployment Group Agent?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am trying to install the Azure DevOps Deployment Group Agent as described in
[Provision agents for deployment groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/howto-provision-deployment-group-agents?view=azure-devops).

Step 6 includes the following guidance: `When prompted for the user account, press Return to accept the defaults.`

However, the default configures the agent to run under the `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` account, and I'm hesitant to give full access to a process that runs commands it obtained over the web. What are the minimum permissions/roles I need to give an agent so it will function properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow this doc: [Provision agents for deployment groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/howto-provision-deployment-group-agents?view=azure-devops) to accept the defaults configures the agent to run under the `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` account, it is required for the agent to run without issues.

If you run it under other accounts/roles, it will fail with unexpected errors as reported here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/running-azure-devops-agent-as-domain-account-fails/712546 and https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/running-azure-devops-deployment-group-agent-using/1107600, etc.

In addition, there is [a suggestion ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/create-deployment-agent-with-service-account-havin/1118600) in Developer community about this requirement. You can vote and follow this ticket. You can also create a new suggestion ticket [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion). The product group will review these tickets regularly, and consider take it as roadmap.